# How to refer to the empirical study involved in the thesis?

Tags: writing, writing-style

Should I always refer to it as "the empirical study of/ involved in this thesis"? I found it too lengthy when I need to refer to it frequently in the thesis. Is there another shorter term to refer to it?

Comment: Many software packages can replace mis-spelt words automatically, so make use of that "teso" is replaced by "the emprirical study of/ involved in this thesis"...

Comment: I was asking about whether there is another way of referring to it.

Comment: When you put "too lengthy" I thought is was that you found it too difficult to type... Now you have edited your question to clarify that.

Answer (score 1):

If there is no ambiguity, "The Study" should do after the first instance. You could even say, at the first usage

> ...the empirical study of this thesis (*The Study*)...

This would make it a sort of keyword for the remainder of the thesis.

If there might be ambiguity, then *The Present Study* would probably be enough to clarify.